# Adding a different icon to a TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, icons

I'm using a `TreeView` that contain several items:

```
<TreeViewItem Header="PL3 Line 1" IsExpanded="true">
<TreeViewItem Header="Live Update" Selected="TreeViewItem_Selected" Height="20" Width="98"/>
<TreeViewItem Header="Archives" Selected="TreeViewItem_Selected_1"/>
<TreeViewItem Header="Archives / days" Selected="TreeViewItem_Selected_100"></TreeViewItem/>
```

and I want to add different icon to each item, I have tried it by using a `StackPanel`:

```
<TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="../Images/japan.png"></Image>
            <Label Content="Japan"></Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </TreeViewItem.Header>
</TreeViewItem>
```

but when I click on it, the event "Selected is not triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you did not specify the Selected event.
It should be something like:

```
<TreeViewItem Selected="SelectedEvent">
    <TreeViewItem.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="../Images/japan.png"></Image>
            <Label Content="Japan"></Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </TreeViewItem.Header>
</TreeViewItem>
```